# Quill: author-advanced class does not fire on "keyup" event

Tags: html, events, keyup, quill

Using Quill, I am trying to store the text within a span element ("span .author-advanced" class) upon releasing the key, but the event keyup does not get fired. I realized that in pure Javascript i can solve this problem by changing the contenteditable using a nested span, but that implies I have to modify Quill.

I there a way to solve this problem without modifying Quill?

Comment: There are some details missing from your question. What are you trying to fire a keyup event on? What text are you trying to store in the span, or where are you getting "the text" from?

Comment: I'm trying to fire a keyup event on a span element of class author-advanced that i am currently typing, so I can store the span in a variable. The text are just regular keyboard input, like "jpaugh is such a nice guy"

Comment: More information on the pure Javascript solution with nested spans would be helpful. Otherwise I don't believe you can attach a key listeners to just any DOM element, such as ordinary spans: http://jsfiddle.net/vqpp1hr5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aBYpt/14/  here is one example in javascript, but we cannot figure out a way to do so using Quill   :(